# Почему не выводятся оба шаблона на страницу?

Tags: vue.js

Хочу на страницу вывести Header и Footer.

Файлы папки **/src**:

```
- FooterWeb.vue
- HeaderWeb.vue
- main.js
```

**FooterWeb.vue**:

```
<template>
    <div id="footer">
        Footer
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'CustomFooter'
    }
</script>
```

**HeaderWeb.vue**:

```
<template>
    <div id="header">
        Header
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'CustomHeader'
    }
</script>
<style src="./fontawesome/css/all.css"></style>
```

**main.js**:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import CustomHeader from './HeaderWeb'
import CustomFooter from './FooterWeb'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: { CustomHeader, CustomFooter },
    template: '<CustomHeader/><CustomFooter/>'
})
```

В итоге выводится только Header. а если *template* сделать так: `template: '<CustomFooter/>'` - то выводиться только Footer соответственно.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: попробуйте обернуть это в один див <div><CustomHeader/><CustomFooter/></div>

Comment: @radar4ick помогло! спасибо большое! можете оформить это в ответ, отмечу :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оберните `<CustomHeader/><CustomFooter/>` в `<div>`, чтобы был один корневой элемент. 
Вот так:

```
<div>
  <CustomHeader/>
  <CustomFooter/>
</div>
```